# XML and Dynamic Textfields

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I'm trying to import the content of an xml inside dynamic textfields. I managed to do it, but my project asks for more:
Basically, I have a list of names (say Auguste, Tibere, Claude). When I click on one of them, a biography of him appears (an image and several textfields). The two textfields are filled with parts of the xml depending of which name I clicked. 
This part doesn't work... No matter which name I click, the textfields don't change.
I hope you can help :).
Here is my code:

```
var myXML:XML = new XML();
var XML_URL:String = "assets/fiches.xml";
var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL);
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL);
myLoader.addEventListener("complete", xmlLoaded);
var list:Number = 0;

function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void{
    myXML = XML(myLoader.data);
    fnPeople(myXML);
};

function fnPeople(peopleList:XML):void{
nom.text = peopleList.person.name.text()[list];
vie.text = peopleList.person.comment.text()[list];
};

/*Auguste*/
liste_a1.auguste_liste.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_auguste);
function fl_auguste(MouseEvent: Event): void {
auguste.visible = true;
close_fiches_btn.visible = true;
nom.visible = true;
vie.visible=true;
list=0;
};

/*Tibère*/
tibere_arbre.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_tibere);
function fl_tibere(MouseEvent: Event): void {
tibere.visible = true;
close_fiches_btn.visible = true;
tibere_txt.visible = true;
    list=1
};
```

The XML file is pretty simple:

```
<people>

<person>
<name>Auguste</name>
<comment>text</comment>
</person>

<person>
<name>Tibere</name>
<comment>text</comment>
</person>

</people>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textfields don't update because you don't invoke update function `fnPeople` anywhere. Add following row to the functions `fl_auguste` and `fl_tibere`:

```
fnPeople(myXML);
```

This should update textfields.